# Dozer, how to map from java.util.Map to complex type?

Tags: getter, dozer, complextype, dictionary

I'd like to map from a java.util.Map to a complex type, let's call it Abc.

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>java.util.Map</class-a>
  <class-b bean-factory="xyz.AbcBeanFactory" factory-bean-id="AbcBeanFactory">
    xyz.Abc
  </class-b>
  <field>
    <a>Name</a>
    <b>companyName</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

With that I get this error (which is comprehensible):
*org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field (Name) in class (interface java.util.Map)*

Ok, how do I map from a java.util.Map that has an entry with the key 'Name'? Do I have to create a wrapper object that holds that java.util.Map and provide getters/setters for each entry in that map that I want to map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find details for mapping a Map [in the Dozer documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html). You need to provide a key not a plain field. Here is an example:

Class Abc:

```
package com.test;

public class Abc {
    private String companyName;
    private String companyAddress;

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCompanyAddress() {
        return companyAddress;
    }

    public void setCompanyAddress(String companyAddress) {
        this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
    }
}
```

Mapping file:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.util.Map</class-a>
    <class-b>com.test.Abc</class-b>
    <field>
        <a key="name">this</a>
        <b>companyName</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a key="address">this</a>
        <b>companyAddress</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Test code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "Company Inc.");
map.put("address", "XYZ Commercial Street");

Abc destObject =  dozerMapper.map(map, Abc.class);
```