# how to simply get a field in a java Map hierarchy?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a java.util.Map named rootMap.
    rootMap["level1"]
is another Map (let's call it map1)
    map1["level2]
is another Map etc...In short words, I have a Map hierarchy.

My need : simply and directly get a deep field with a short API like :
    get(rootMap, "level1.level2.field")
I thought leveraging Dozer but does something simpler exist ?
Thanks !

Comment: I think you should write your own method to do it step by step. J

Comment: ok, I know that, I just wanted no know if a simple library would do that for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a map of maps

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

You can access some inner map by

```
outerMap.get("inner map key");
```

And to get a value of inner map you do

```
outerMap.get("inner map key").get("the key");
```

So, as you can see, you have to pipe calls to `Map.get` in order to get inner maps.

Comment: ok, I know that, I just wanted no know if a simple library would do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

I actually need a Map2POJO mapping, so I finally used Dozer to do that, as previously suggested in [Dozer, how to map from java.util.Map to complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395865/dozer-how-to-map-from-java-util-map-to-complex-type)